# How do you calculate a (non-self) correlation matrix in pandas with multicolumns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, correlation, multi-index

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe with multicolumns, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
iterables = [['a', 'b'], ['1', '2']]
my_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], columns=my_index)
```

Then `df` produces

```
first  a   b
second 1 2 1 2
0      1 2 3 4
1      5 6 7 8
```

Now if I want the self-correlation of `df['a']` with itself, that's straight-forward: `df['a'].corr()` gets me that. Note that such a correlation has shape `(2, 2)`.

What I would like to do is calculate the correlation matrix of `df['a']` with `df['b']`. Supposedly, the code `df['a'].corrwith(df['b'])` should give me this. This code does run, but the result has shape `(2,)`, which doesn't look right to me. Why should the self-correlation matrix given by `.corr()` give a result with a different shape than a correlation given by `.corrwith()`? I need a correlation matrix of the same shape as `df['a'].corr()`, because I want to plot Seaborn heatmaps, and I need the 2D correlation matrix.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this problem was to recognize that the result of the `.corr()` DataFrame function is itself a pandas DataFrame. If we run the code in the question, and then use the `.loc` function, we can get a subset of the correlation matrix. The result of `df.corr()` is

```py
        first   a           b
        second  1   2       1   2
first   second              
a          1    1.0 1.0     1.0 1.0
           2    1.0 1.0     1.0 1.0
b          1    1.0 1.0     1.0 1.0
           2    1.0 1.0     1.0 1.0
```

and the result of `df.corr().loc['a', 'b']` is

```py
second  1    2
second          
1       1.0  1.0
2       1.0  1.0
```

This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the corr() function from the DataFRame, not from the Series.

It would look like:

```py
In [1]:
# Create the Dataframe
import pandas as pd
iterables = [['a', 'b'], ['1', '2']]
my_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], columns=my_index)
df

Out [1]:
first     a       b
second  1   2   1   2
0       1   2   3   4
1       5   6   7   8
```

```py
In [2]:
## Get the correlation matrix
df.corr()

Out [2]:
        first     a           b
        second  1   2       1   2
first   second              
a          1    1.0 1.0     1.0 1.0
           2    1.0 1.0     1.0 1.0
b          1    1.0 1.0     1.0 1.0
           2    1.0 1.0     1.0 1.0
```

## EDIT

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)

*You can choose the function behind it
method : {‘pearson’, ‘kendall’, ‘spearman’} or callable

pearson : standard correlation coefficient

kendall : Kendall Tau correlation coefficient
spearman : Spearman rank correlation

callable: callable with input two 1d ndarrays*

Comment: When you use `df['a']` in the multi-column setting, the result is a DataFrame, not a Series. You've not explained how I could extract just the correlation of `df['a']` with `df['b']`.

Comment: For multi columns then do : `df[['a', 'b']].corr()`

Comment: The result should be of shape `(2, 2)`, right? How would I extract just the results I want from `df[['a', 'b']].corr()`?

Comment: Looks like, since the result of `.corr()` is itself a DataFrame, I can use the `.loc` function to get what I want (plus the correlation matrix is symmetric): `df.corr().loc['a', 'b']`. Yes, this is giving me what I want.

Comment: Okay good for you !  Yes a correlation matrix is a square matrix with the same rank than the number of vector being compared. In your case, because you have Multi index, you are comparing 4 vectors: a.1, a.2, b.1 and b.2 .  That's why the result of `df.[['a', 'b']].corr()` is a rank 4 square matrix.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: If the answer "gives want you want", please also upvote/accept it... :)

Comment: @Cleb: Yes, I'm very well aware of the courtesy of accepting answers. I was waiting for Benoit to add my code to his answer, but he never did. I've since edited my code into his answer, and when the edit is accepted, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: My edit got rejected, so I'm going to type up my own answer.